# vuejs: Trying to focus the input using v-el directive

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a wizard login form where the Mobile Number is first entered and 
password is entered next.

Here am trying to focus the password input using

```
this.$$.passwordInput.focus()
```

however if am getting the error given below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
```

The full code is below

index.html

```
<div id="login">
  <div v-if="flow.mobile">
    <form v-on="submit: checkmobile">
        <p>
          Mobile Number<br>
          <input type="text" v-model="mobile_number" v-el="mobileNumber">
        </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div v-if="flow.password">
    <form v-on="submit: checkpassword">
        <p>
          Password<br>
          <input type="password" v-model="password" v-el="passwordInput">
        </p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

script.js

```
var demo = new Vue({
el: '#login',
data: {
    flow: {
        mobile: true,
        password: false
    }
},
methods: {
    checkmobile: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.flow.mobile = false;
        this.flow.password = true;
        this.$$.passwordInput.focus();
    },
    checkpassword: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your passwordInput is inside a v-if block, which only gets rendered when you set `flow.password` to true; However Vue uses asynchronous rendering, so the v-if block will not be rendered immediately. You can use `Vue.nextTick` to wait until it does:

```
this.flow.password = true;
var self = this;
Vue.nextTick(function () {
  self.$$.passwordInput.focus();
});
```

Read the guide about async rendering for [more details](http://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Understanding_Async_Updates).

Comment: I'll just add this, if you are referencing your el this inside another method, the Vue.nextTick lives inside that method. That wasn't abundantly clear.

Answer (score 13):

In Vue.js 2.x you can create your own directive to focus a field automatically:

```
Vue.directive('focus', {
    inserted: function (el) {
        el.focus();
    },
    update: function (el) {
        Vue.nextTick(function() {
              el.focus();
        })
    }
})
```

Then you can use `v-focus` attribute on inputs and other elements:

```
<input v-focus>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/cap43pdn/

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for my input fields in a v-for loop.

Comment: I had to modify this solution to remove the update: part. I had two fields, username and password, and marked the username with v-focus. When entering the password, the focus would jump back to username with every character. I can imagine that perhaps by removing the update function, I will miss out on some events that should trigger the focus on the username, but so far have not run into it.

Comment: A concise and working answer with a fiddle, I'd give you 2 up-votes if I could. Thanks.

Comment: Example documented at [this page](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

Answer (score 11):

If you are using vuejs 2, you should read this:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced

--

In this case, in your template:

use `ref="passwordInput"` instead `v-el="passwordInput"`

and in your method:

```
this.$refs.passwordInput.focus()
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'passwordInput' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Glad this worked for some of you.
I have no idea why, but after trying every conceivable variation of the accepted answer I could not get the $$.ref property when using v-repeat.
I could only access the newly created dom elements like so:

```
new Vue({
el: '#reporting_create',
data: {
    recipients: {
        0: {
            fname: null,
            lname: null,
            email: null,
            registration: false,
            report: false
        }
    },
    curRec:1
},
methods: {
    addRecipient: function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.recipients.$add(
            this.curRec,
            {
                fname: null,
                lname: null,
                email: null,
                registration: false,
                report: false
            }
        );
        var num = this.curRec;
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            console.log(this._children[num].$$.rowrec);
            newSwitches.find('.switch').bootstrapSwitch();
        })

        this.curRec++;
    }
}})
```

html:

```
<template v-repeat="recipients">
        <div class="row" v-el="rowrec">
            <div>{{$key}}</div>
        </div>
</template>
```

The addRecipients function was called outside the v-repeat so even the suggested answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853337/vuejs-focus-on-input-using-v-el-directive-inside-v-repeat-directive) did couldn't help

Not sure if there is an issue with doing it this way but it works and I'm tired.

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js 1 works a bit different.

Example:

```
  <textarea v-el:model_message></textarea>
```

JS:

```
this.$els.model_message.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue.js 2.0, you should do the following:

```
<input type="text" v-model="currentItem.name" ref="txtName">
```

So you can access this input by using the $refs object:

```
this.$refs.txtName.focus();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'txtName' of undefined. This in the "created" method.

Answer (score 0):

Vue v2's documentation uses focus as an example in writing custom directives. All of the needed code is supplied with the example, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html. First you must register the directive. The link shows how to register it locally on the component.

```
// Register a global custom directive called `v-focus`
Vue.directive('focus', {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
  inserted: function (el) {
    // Focus the element
    el.focus()
  }
})
```

Having done this, you are now able to use v-focus on an element:

```
<input v-focus>
```

Like so.