# VueJs: Focus on Input using v-el Directive inside v-repeat Directive

Tags: javascript, html, list, laravel, vue.js

I display a list by using the v-repeat directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/ftc9ev7p/1/

Please notice the dynamically created argument of the **v-el** directive, which is made of

```
v-el="inputField{{task.id}}"
```

or alternatively

```
v-el="{{'inputField' + task.id }}"
```

Still it doesn't get recognized, since I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
```

I want to click the **edit button** and have the according input field focused on.

A similar syntax works, when I dynamically add a css class. Just uncomment the line with the .focus() and click "edit".

```js
  new Vue({
    el: '#tasks',

    data: {
      "tasks": [{
        "id": 25,
        "body": "Slack Noooo Yes",
        "completed": true,
        "created_at": "2015-08-05 17:00:26",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-05 17:00:26"
      }, {
        "id": 27,
        "body": "And",
        "completed": false,
        "created_at": "2015-08-05 17:22:14",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-05 17:22:14"
      }, {
        "id": 28,
        "body": "Happiness",
        "completed": false,
        "created_at": "2015-08-05 17:22:16",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-05 17:22:16"
      }, {
        "id": 29,
        "body": "Love",
        "completed": true,
        "created_at": "2015-08-06 07:45:02",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-06 07:45:02"
      }],

      newTask: ''
    },

    methods: {
      editTask: function(task) {

        var inputField = 'inputField' + task.id;
        alert(inputField);

        var self = this;
        self.$$.inputField.focus();

        document.querySelector(".task" + task.id).className += " edit";
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.8/vue.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tasks">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-repeat="task: tasks">
      <td class="todo">
        <span class="task{{ task.id }}" v-on="dblclick: editTask(task)">
      {{ task.body }}
     </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="editInputField" v-el="inputField{{ task.id }}" value="{{ task.body }}" v-on="keyup:editTask(task) | key 'enter'">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" v-on="click: editTask(task)">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ftc9ev7p/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really have to number the elements by v-el since you can get a child ViewModel created by v-repeat. The official guide is on http://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Invoke_Handler_with_Expression.

You can pass `this` to `editTask` in `v-on` and then you can get the child ViewModel by the first argument:

```
<div v-repeat="task: tasks">
  <span class="task" v-el="label" v-on="dblclick: editTask(this)">
  <input type="text" v-el="inputField" class="editInputField" value="{{ task.body }}">
</div>
```

```
editTask: function (task) {
    task.$$.inputField.focus();
    task.$$.label.className += " edit";
}
```

Also you can get the targetVM by using `event.targetVM` in the function without the need of passing this to your function.

```
<div v-repeat="task: tasks">
  <span class="task" v-el="label" v-on="dblclick: editTask()">
  <input type="text" v-el="inputField" class="editInputField" value="{{ task.body }}">
</div>
```

```
editTask: function () {
    event.targetVM.$$.inputField.focus();
    event.targetVM.$$.label.className += " edit";
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ef18uq/1/

Comment: What does this represent: `$$`?